# Get position of the crosshair within a Directx game in python

Tags: python

I have recently gotten in trying to program an AI to play a game after watching the "Python plays GTA5" (https://youtu.be/ks4MPfMq8aQ) which basically makes a self driving car. Since I do not want to directly copy it as I want to learn how to implement it in TF2 which is a source game. The problem is that the game is played in first person and I would need to get the mouse position within the game in order to train it where to shoot. I have already tried win32 in order to get the mouse position but it just returns that the mouse is in the middle of the screen. Is there any possible way that I could get the position of the crosshair?

Comment: When is the crosshair ever not in the center of the screen?

Comment: yeah but is there any way to get the mouse position so I can log where I am looking at

Comment: Mouse position is not gonna tell you much, you can turn infinitely while your mouse remains at the exact same position at the edge of the screen. Look at mouse input instead.

Comment: Do you know of anything that could point me in the right direction Ive only ben able to find stuff for finding the mouse position on screen